# SQL - Select not repeated rows from 2 tables for some users?

Tags: sql

I have a main page where a user can post a photo. DB have  2 tables (perhaps they are badly built) with 4 users. I use MySQL.

table1

```
id  |  photo |  user
1   |  a     |  me
2   |  b     |  dad
3   |  c     |  mom
4   |  d     |  sister
```

table2

```
id  |  photo |  user
1   |  a     |  me
2   |  b     |  me
3   |  c     |  me
```

I've seen every photo of my dad, mom and sister, then, table2 have rows indicating I have seen those photos.

With this code I can't do what I want.

```
select * from table1 where photo not in (select photo from table2)
```

But then, my mom, dad and sister haven't seen the other photos, so that's a mistake, They should be able to see the photos of each other and they can't.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you rename table1 and table2 into something more accurate?  It'll make it easier to understand and answer your question

Comment: Can you show us your expected output please?

Comment: Imagine 4 images that 4 users (1 per user) have uploaded. 4 users can see every photo. OK.
Then If I see the 4 photos, I'll not be able to see those 4 photos again. But if the other 3 users haven't seen the photo yet, they can still see these photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I Undestand correctly you want to show the photo's in table1 that haven't been seen by the user in table2.

To do this you need to get a unique list of pictures and a unique list of users:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [user] FROM table1
SELECT DISTINCT [photo] FROM table1
```

We then want to join those to results together:

```
SELECT  *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [user] FROM #table1) users
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [photo] FROM #table1) photos ON 1=1
```

The `1=1` means that we join each photo with each user.

This will give you a list of every photo and every user:

```
USER | PHOTO
dad    a
dad    c
dad    b
dad    d
me     a
me     b
me     c
me     d
mom    a
mom    b
mom    c
mom    d
Sister a
Sister b
Sister c
Sister d
```

The final step then is to filter out the photo's that you've already seen (as recorded in table2). To do this we left join to table2 and find all the null's:

```
SELECT  *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [user] FROM table1) users
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [photo] FROM table1) photos ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON photos.photo = table2.photo AND table2.[user] = users.[user]
WHERE table2.id IS NULL
```

If instead you want to see which pictures each user has seen, change the where clause to `WHERE table2.id IS NOT NULL`

Comment: As a side note I'd probably consider renamming your tables to something other than table1 and table2. Also I'd consider renaming the user columns to something like 'uploadedByUser' for table1 and 'viewedByUser' for table2. Also you might want to create a users table

Comment: Also you might want to add the current user to the where clause to limit the results

Comment: This is the idea! Lemme check and i tell you something ;)